# What do you call an organism that is dying out (failing to evolve successfully)?

Tags: single-word-requests

In evolution, a successful organism can be said to have adapted or evolved. What about an organism that is clearly going to die out?

The example I have in mind is a parasite that kills its host.

Comment: what has your search revealed?

Comment: It's becoming *extinct*.

Comment: The word I want won't be be too scientific or technical. It should be applicable to a parasitic person or business. 'Doomed' is not the right word but it captures the tragically wrong path taken by my subject.

Comment: I wish you'd said that in the first place, Ken! In fact it would be great if this site insisted on questions including details of 'what is it *for?*' A novel, advertising, essay, article - use such different language! And providing more or longer surrounding 'example text'. This context dramatically alters the answers that one would give! A parasitic person is not going to need the same word as a parasitic plant,  for example...

Comment: What is 'a parasitic person in business', Ken? Do you mean, 'they destroy the company they work for?' In which case, how are *they* 'doomed'? Isn't the company the one that's 'doomed'? Please clarify.

Comment: Sorry, Jelila (it wasn't I who downvoted your answer). You are right about the need for context. It's my first question here.

Comment: About business, I meant a parasitic business, living off competitors in an unsustainable way, eventually killing them and itself.

Comment: In a general way, we are surrounded by successful well-adapted organisms, but there are also many that are on the wrong path and will not survive. There must be - otherwise evolution would be over. 

Regarding human behaviour, there is much debate about paths to success or failure and disagreement over what is sustainable or not.

I am looking for a word to describe an organism that is bound for extinction. Perhaps not willing to adapt!

Comment: [Many parasites in nature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parasitoid) [kill their hosts](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/9437/why-do-parasites-sometimes-kill-their-hosts) and then jump on to a different host. That seems completely unrelated to the Darwinian concepts of (failure of) adaptation and evolution. An organism that is on its way to extinction is _moribund_, but I’m not sure what the rest of your question even has to do with this.

Comment: The worst parasite on earth is mankind which is killing its host (the earth) in such an effective way that it proves mankind is not evolving. "Self-destroying" is, I believe , the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"ill-adapted"** seems to be the term you're looking for.

> - [**The ill-adapted parasite species slays its host species and goes extinct**](https://dspace.library.colostate.edu/bitstream/handle/10217/36773/FACFPHIL_Rolston_2016_Disvalues-in-Nature-b.pdf?sequence=4); better-adapted parasites co-exist with their hosts, and the best-adapted will benefit their hosts at the species and even at the individual level. Overvirulence to the host decreases the parasite's chances of survival; a parasite can increase its chances by benefiting its host organism
> - [**Symposium on factors influencing host-parasitic relationships**](http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/003591575504801219) "It would appear, therefore, that in many instances the borderline between successful
>   parasitism and disease is an exceedingly narrow one and it may be supposed that the changes
>   required to upset the balance are not only of a very varied nature but sometimes need only
>   be very slight in order to allow **an ill-adapted parasite** to multiply exceedingly and to cause
>   disease.

[ill-adapted](http://sinonimos-online.com/english/ill-adapted.html) means "unsuitable, inappropriate"

Comment: wry, I like it..

Answer (score 1):

The premise of the biology of your question is a bit faulty, but I will leave that to Biology.SE.

I think the term you are looking for is either

> maladaptive

in terms of a trait (I would prefer this usage in this context), or

> maladapted

in terms of the organism. For example, one could say

> Ken birds are maladapted to the warming conditions in the arctic and are in danger of extinction.

The phrase

> ...the level of pathogen virulence is **likely to be maladaptive** not only for the host but also the pathogen.

fits the specific context you are referring to. (verbatim from *[Longdon, B., Hadfield, J. D., Day, J. P., Smith, S. C., McGonigle, J. E., Cogni, R., ... & Jiggins, F. M. (2015). The causes and consequences of changes in virulence following pathogen host shifts. PLoS Pathogens, 11(3), e1004728.](http://journals.plos.org/plospathogens/article?id=10.1371/journal.ppat.1004728)*)

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. This site prefers citations be done by hyperlinks , but you have done well with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The organism is becoming (or "going") **extinct**.

Answer (score -2):

Evanesce, evanescing, evanescent

Gradually fade, disappear, or die out.

It means 'to pass out of sight, memory, or existence'.

Example:

- the evanescent host is gradually dying
- the evanescent star finally disappeared in the distance
- Marilyn Monroe shone brightly as a candle, then evanesced
- the evanescence of a shooting star makes it hard to catch

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/evanesce

https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/evanescence